# Why did hmac generator generate hmac hash different from spring web app and JUnit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, hmac

I sent a request with same content incl. german umlaut and hash like in JUnit to spring web app. But HMAC encryption works differently both. HMAC encryption can encrypte at JUnit the same hash like the setting hash. The setting hash is encrpted from another server and sent to my spring web app.

Sending request to tomcat and starting hmac validator

```
allValues [51, 54, 49, 50, 50, 50, 57, 51, 57, 52, 49, 51, 55, 52, 46, 57, 53, 50, 51, 48, 50, 77, 97, 110, 117, 101, 108, 32, 71, 110, 101, 114, 108, 105, 99, 104, 52, 50, 54, 51, 53, 52, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 57, 52, 54, 56, 86, 72, 97, 109, 98, 117, 114, 103, 99, 99, 68, 69, 69, 85, 82, 49, 52, 50, 49, 51, 32, 77, 111, 110, 97, 116, 101, 32, 84, 101, 105, 108, 110, 97, 104, 109, 101, 118, 101, 114, 103, -61, -68, 116, 117, 110, 103, 32, 102, -61, -68, 114, 32, 68, 71, 83, 32, 40, 100, 101, 114, 122, 101, 105, 116, 32, 76, 101, 118, 101, 108, 32, 65, 49, 41, 97, 114, 103, 111, 110, 105, 115, 116, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 49, 53, 54, 48, 48, 57, 55, 53, 55, 51, 77, 97, 110, 117, 101, 108, 57, 51, 54, 50, 53, 49, 51, 52, 101, 57, 54, 102, 53, 56, 48, 54, 100, 99, 53, 98, 99, 57, 101, 53, 98, 98, 57, 53, 57, 55, 53, 53, 51, 56, 56, 102, 71, 110, 101, 114, 108, 105, 99, 104, 116, 101, 115, 116, 49, 55, 46, 52, 97, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 45, 49, 52, 50, 49, 45, 48, 45, 48, 45, 51, 51, 56, 55, 57, 55, 52, 46, 57, 53, 55, 52, 46, 57, 53, 57, 51, 54, 50, 55, 52, 46, 57, 53, 49, 52, 50, 49, 45, 56, 98, 49, 99, 55, 48, 98, 101, 49, 56, 97, 57, 48, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 100, 98, 101, 114, 103, 119, 101, 103, 32, 49, 50, 51, 32, 77, 111, 110, 97, 116, 101, 32, 65, 98, 111, 32, 45, 32, 109, 97, 110, 105, 109, 117, 110, 100, 111, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 116, 101, 100, 97, 112, 112, 111, 105, 110, 116, 101, 100, 51, 50, 49, 54, 55, 51, 52, 56, 55, 49, 53, 53, 50, 49, 53, 50, 51, 55, 51, 49, 53, 55, 57, 52, 57, 57, 48, 48, 49, 57, 46, 48, 48, 50, 50, 53, 56, 55]
    hmac hash 5dffe6e4b92ff855411a73eea34d74909e25678b1b768dcb8081dd764200f7fefa710beacf26b5d141c362fa5a3ea9ed
    hash      65e2f454df692db7ccb34c49e71349dc351f62ca47eaca2a08ddb6c5baa634d9baa691358c69361dc01d7f73681820ed
```

Starting with jUnit hmac validator

```
allValues [51, 54, 49, 50, 50, 50, 57, 51, 57, 52, 49, 51, 55, 52, 46, 57, 53, 50, 51, 48, 50, 77, 97, 110, 117, 101, 108, 32, 71, 110, 101, 114, 108, 105, 99, 104, 52, 50, 54, 51, 53, 52, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 57, 52, 54, 56, 86, 72, 97, 109, 98, 117, 114, 103, 99, 99, 68, 69, 69, 85, 82, 49, 52, 50, 49, 51, 32, 77, 111, 110, 97, 116, 101, 32, 84, 101, 105, 108, 110, 97, 104, 109, 101, 118, 101, 114, 103, -61, -68, 116, 117, 110, 103, 32, 102, -61, -68, 114, 32, 68, 71, 83, 32, 40, 100, 101, 114, 122, 101, 105, 116, 32, 76, 101, 118, 101, 108, 32, 65, 49, 41, 97, 114, 103, 111, 110, 105, 115, 116, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 49, 53, 54, 48, 48, 57, 55, 53, 55, 51, 77, 97, 110, 117, 101, 108, 57, 51, 54, 50, 53, 49, 51, 52, 101, 57, 54, 102, 53, 56, 48, 54, 100, 99, 53, 98, 99, 57, 101, 53, 98, 98, 57, 53, 57, 55, 53, 53, 51, 56, 56, 102, 71, 110, 101, 114, 108, 105, 99, 104, 116, 101, 115, 116, 49, 55, 46, 52, 97, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 45, 49, 52, 50, 49, 45, 48, 45, 48, 45, 51, 51, 56, 55, 57, 55, 52, 46, 57, 53, 55, 52, 46, 57, 53, 57, 51, 54, 50, 55, 52, 46, 57, 53, 49, 52, 50, 49, 45, 56, 98, 49, 99, 55, 48, 98, 101, 49, 56, 97, 57, 48, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 100, 98, 101, 114, 103, 119, 101, 103, 32, 49, 50, 51, 32, 77, 111, 110, 97, 116, 101, 32, 65, 98, 111, 32, 45, 32, 109, 97, 110, 105, 109, 117, 110, 100, 111, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 116, 101, 100, 97, 112, 112, 111, 105, 110, 116, 101, 100, 51, 50, 49, 54, 55, 51, 52, 56, 55, 49, 53, 53, 50, 49, 53, 50, 51, 55, 51, 49, 53, 55, 57, 52, 57, 57, 48, 48, 49, 57, 46, 48, 48, 50, 50, 53, 56, 55]
hmac hash 65e2f454df692db7ccb34c49e71349dc351f62ca47eaca2a08ddb6c5baa634d9baa691358c69361dc01d7f73681820ed
hash      65e2f454df692db7ccb34c49e71349dc351f62ca47eaca2a08ddb6c5baa634d9baa691358c69361dc01d7f73681820ed
```

Source code:

```
        @Component
         public class HMACValidator {

        private final SevDeskProperties sevDeskProperties;

        public HMACValidator(SevDeskProperties sevDeskProperties) {
            this.sevDeskProperties = sevDeskProperties;
        }

        public void validateHMAC(TransactionPayOne transactionPayOne, String hash) {

            byte[] key = transactionPayOne.getPortalid()
                    .equals(sevDeskProperties.getAboPortalId()) ?
                    sevDeskProperties.getAboKey().getBytes() :
                    sevDeskProperties.getSingleKey().getBytes();

            String allValues = getAllValues(transactionPayOne);
            logger.debug("allValues " + allValues);

            String hmacSha384Encode;
            try {
                logger.debug("allValues" + Arrays.toString(allValues.getBytes("UTF-8")));
                hmacSha384Encode = HMAC_SHA384_encode(key, allValues);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not encode the values",e);
            }

            logger.debug("hmac hash " + hmacSha384Encode);
            logger.debug("hash        " + hash);

           if (!hmacSha384Encode.equals(hash)) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("message is not valid ");
            }
        }

        public static String HMAC_SHA384_encode(byte[] key, String message) throws Exception {

            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(
                    key, HmacAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA_384.getName());

            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HmacAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA_384.getName());
            mac.init(keySpec);
            byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            return Hex.encodeHexString(rawHmac);
        }

// Getting all values without key in json of transaction data
        private String getAllValues(TransactionPayOne transactionPayOne) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Map<String, Object> mapJson;
            try {
                mapJson = objectMapper.readValue(transactionPayOne.getJson().getBytes("UTF-8"), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse json");
            }
            return mapJson.values().stream().map(value -> {
                if (value instanceof Map) {
                    value = ((Map) value).values().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(""));
                }
                return (String) value;
            }).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you send a string without the umlaut in it?

Comment: Without the umlaut same problem.